# Unable to compile X11 with bitbake

Tags: linux, dependencies, yocto, x11, bitbake

I've added

```
DISTRO_FEATURES_append = " x11"
```

to my `local.conf` as I will need access to `Xrandr` (which depends on X11). As soon as I add x11 to the DISTRO_FEATURES, I keep getting the following when invoking bitbake:

```
| checking for GLAMOR... yes
| checking for GBM... no
| configure: error: Glamor for Xorg requires gbm >= 10.2.0
| NOTE: The following config.log files may provide further information.
| NOTE: /home/yocto/rzg_vlp_v3.0.0/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/xserver-xorg/2_1.20.8-r0/build/config.log
| ERROR: configure failed
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
| ERROR: Execution of '/home/yocto/rzg_vlp_v3.0.0/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/xserver-xorg/2_1.20.8-r0/temp/run.do_configure.143696' failed with exit code 1
ERROR: Task (/home/yocto/rzg_vlp_v3.0.0/build/../poky/meta/recipes-graphics/xorg-xserver/xserver-xorg_1.20.8.bb:do_configure) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 4840 tasks of which 4796 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.

Summary: 1 task failed:
  /home/yocto/rzg_vlp_v3.0.0/build/../poky/meta/recipes-graphics/xorg-xserver/xserver-xorg_1.20.8.bb:do_configure
```

`libgbm` on openembedded.org appears to be at version `10.0` only: https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/recipe/131409/
How can I get this resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to fix it is to change the xserver-xorg's `PACKAGECONFIG` and remove the need for GBM.
Looking at the `poky/meta/recipes-graphics/xorg-xserver/xserver-xorg.inc`, GBM is only mentioned in this line:

```
PACKAGECONFIG[glamor] = "--enable-glamor,--disable-glamor,libepoxy virtual/libgbm,libegl"
```

Sadly, just removing the `virtual/libgbm` is not enough and you also need to disable glamor completely while keeping the `libepoxy` package.

So I suggest you create a `xserver-xorg_1.20.8.bbappend` file which the following content:

```
PACKAGECONFIG[glamor] = "--disable-glamor,--disable-glamor,libepoxy,libegl"
```

I know it is a hack. But it fixes your issue